# What style is this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, style-identification

[image: I would love to know what style of image this is?]

Knowing the style will enable me to go and find tutorials to help me get started.

Comment: As for 'style' I'd say 'digital illustration'. It's not really a particular style more specific than that. As for subject matter, I think the answers here sum that up well.

Comment: I appreciate the answers here i really do.  As for the down vote for asking a question = brrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr (cold place)!

Comment: Hey Mikey. Sorry you feel like the reception was a chilly one. Down votes aren't about being rude, but it's more about usefulness of the post and how it might help someone else in the future with a similar question. I know it's hard to know where to start sometimes, but it's helpful to explain what you've tried first (were there any search terms you tried that came up empty? what were they?), to show that you've put in some effort before someone else spends their time helping out. It's a give and take. Hope that helps, and I hope you continue to contribute questions and answers to the site.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response.  I do love this site and appreciate it's pathos and logos.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it falls in the "lightwave" and/or "abstract" category. As mentioned below, "smoke" as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would just type "**Smoke Effect Illustrator Tutorial**" into Google. You can see a similar video tutorial [Adobe Illustrator Brush Tutorial - Vector Smoke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2dkvz7zcf0)

The basic idea is to create the outer edges of the smoke and then use create -> blend to make the inside lines of the smoke.